# No horizontal scrollbar in Xcode's Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, osx-mavericks

When I try to edit a storyboard file in Xcode (Version 5.1.1 (5B1008) under OS X 10.9.3) I can only see the vertical scrollbar. Moving around in the horizontal direction between view controllers is not possible. The horizontal bar doesn't show when I hover over it. It only briefly shows when I select past the visible area but it immediately disappears afterwards and I can only scroll by a few pixels at a time this way.

I have tried restarting XCode and the OS but it didn't help. Scrolling was possible before. It stopped working for no apparent reason this morning. I have not updated XCode nor OS X or messed with the system in any way since it was last working. Has anyone encountered this problem before? Do I need to reinstall XCode at this point?

Comment: Hold shift and use the mouse scroll wheel, or, if you have a trackpad, make the two finger scroll gesture horizontally.

Comment: Thanks but shift scrolling doesn't work either. I don't have a access to a usb touchpad or a magic mouse and I am not using a laptop.

Comment: Try resizing the window and panes. Hide the left and right panes so you can see more canvas.  Also use control click to see menu of zoom choices, zoom to 25%. Maybe there is nothing to scroll to.

Comment: I don't see why this question would be downvoted. The whole point is to establish whether this is a bug in xcode or this so due to a setting that can be flipped back on or a corrupted config file that can be reset/deleted without reinstalling xcode/system.

Comment: Holding shift and scrolling worked for me.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's a not bug, it's a feature. It wouldn't be a problem if you use the Apple mouse. There is a workaround for a typical 2/3 button mouse, although it would affect all horizontal bars across the system. Just follow System Preferences->General->Show scroll bars, and select Always.

Comment: Ahh.... a feature, not a bug ;) - or rather a crappy UI? No offense, thanks for sharing!

Comment: worst feature ever. so on a macbook bulk you need to change some shitty setting, when this should be the default!

Answer (score 66):

`Press Shift + Scroll Mouse` this will scroll preview in horizontal

Comment: I've been using a mac for 8 years, and never knew you could do this :D

Comment: Right if you don't need to display scroll bar you can setup settings :

`System Preferences->General->Show scroll bars`

and without scrollbar just use `Mouse Scroll` or `Shif+ mouse scroll`

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this as well. The only solution I found is the following:

So there is a mini map for the storyboard that hovers over the right upper-side.

If you can't see it, just click on the "Adjust Editor Options" button and make sure Minimap is selected.

This is the best way to move around just like you are using the scroll bars.